# How come Node.js Assert doesn't have a notOk() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, assert

I am learning about testing in Node.js using `mocha` and the `assert` module. `assert` has these types of methods:

```
assert.equal();
assert.deepEqual();
assert.deepStrict();
assert.strict();
assert.ok(); // Is the value true?
```

And then there are some opposites:

```
assert.notEqual();
assert.notDeepEqual();
assert.notDeepStrict();
assert.notStrict();
```

But there one missing... Why is there not a `notOk()` method for testing if the resulting value is `false` or not?

This got me thinking that maybe there is something fundamental I am missing about unit testing in general, in that maybe I should only ever be testing if values are true and never false...

For now, I have simply been doing this to test for `falsey` statements:

```
assert.ok(!myValue);
```

Is that how you are supposed to do it? Again, why isn't there just a `notOk()` method since all the other methods have a `not` version?

Comment: You can also check out the Chai assertion library for more methods; they have an `isNotOk` function: http://chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_isnotok

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the docs, it notes that `.ok(value, message)` is equivalent to `assert.equal(!!value, true, message)`. This appears to simply be a convenience function.

It should be noted that while the function is called `ok()`, that does not mean that it is expecting a `true` value from your code. It is expecting a statement to which you want to test the truthiness of. So while your usage of `!myValue` is valid, I think it would be more appropriate to write:

```
assert.ok(myValue === false);
```

The above makes sense semantically, as you are still testing the truthiness of your expression, it just so happens that you are expecting it to be false. To have included a `notOk()` function would imply some ambiguous meaning. *Not OK* implies failure, and so the failure of a `notOk` function might have just seemed a little convoluted.

As for the other methods having their `not` equivalents, I think the language is still meaningful. Saying `notEqual` is implying that you are testing specifically for an inequality, while `notOk` doesn't really make sense. Personally I would just leave out using `ok()` all together, as ok in and of itself it quite ambiguous anyway.

*If you really feel the need, you could simply write your own convenience function too.*

---

I think it is also worth mentioning that this is the source:

```
// 4. Pure assertion tests whether a value is truthy, as determined
// by !!guard.
// assert.ok(guard, message_opt);
// This statement is equivalent to assert.equal(true, !!guard,
// message_opt);. To test strictly for the value true, use
// assert.strictEqual(true, guard, message_opt);.

function ok(value, message) {
    if (!value) fail(value, true, message, '==', assert.ok);
}
assert.ok = ok;
```

Comment: If you are going to use `assert.ok(myValue === false);` then why not just use `assert.equal(myValue, false);` ? I know they are the same thing essentially. But it's weird that `.ok()` exists without `.notOk()` given that it's the same as `assert.equal(myValue,true);`